# Windows Phone 8.1 HERE map API

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, maps, here-api

I am trying to develop an app that access HERE map through its API to get the direction route using transit (not drive or walking) on WP8.1. When I go to [HERE developer website](https://developer.here.com/native-apis), I didn't see the mobile SDK for windows phone. Is HERE maps API still support for WP8.1? Why can't I see HERE maps and its other apps (HERE drive+, HERE transit) in windows phone app store now? Has anyone tried HERE API in WP8.1 before?

The reason I want to use HERE maps API because the native WP8.1 map API does not return route in transit mode.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It was available 4-5 years ago but not anymore.